# Power Automate Flow: Convert json to readable PowerAutomate-Items

Tags: crm, powerapps, power-automate

In CRM I have a 'Doc_Config' value.

[image]

The 'Doc_Config' value gets passed to Power Automate Flow

[image]

With the data I populate an Microsoft Word Document. My problem here is, that instead of the data the raw text is filled into the Word Document.

[image]

Is there a way to convert the raw text so Power Automate recognizes the data I actually want? Like as if it is presented to the Flow like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem: You probably have copied the path for your objects and pasted the path value in your 'Doc_Config' value. Here the problems should be with the @{...} pattern.

Solution: Please, remove @{...} pattern from any objects that you are referring to by their path as in the example below:

incorrect:

```
@{items('Apply_to_each_2')?['productname']}
```

correct:

```
items('Apply_to_each_2')?['productname']
```

Background:
In Power Automate cloud flows, you reference objects that the dynamic content tooling offers. However, sometimes you want to catch objects that the dynamic content tooling cannot see, or does not provide. At these times, you can refer to them by specifying the path for them as in the example below.

```
items('Apply_to_each_2')?['productname']
```

You can observe the path for the objects by hovering over any object that the dynamic content tooling is providing you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to simply parse the data from your array, as it is already JSON.

I will add three links here to Imgur images as I can't post images directly yet, but the idea is very simple:

1. Append your data to your array variable
2. Add a Parse JSON task, click generate from sample, and paste in the JSON you use.
3. Your actions can be used in all other steps now.
   The images will clarify a lot.

[Append your data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOAwI.png)

[Parse your data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXYxf.png)

[Use your data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYdnN.png)